# Pgfplots errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I hope somebody can help me. I am trying to insert some bar charts in my thesis, and I looked for a long time for a solution. I found another question in which the answer was the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval & carT & carD & carR \\
    0--2     & 1.2  & 0.1  & 0.2  \\
    2--5     & 12.8 & 3.8  & 4.9  \\
    5--10    & 15.5 & 10.4 & 13.4 \\
    10--20   & 14.0 & 17.3 & 22.2 \\
    20--50   & 7.9  & 21.1 & 27.0 \\
    50+      & 3.0  & 22.3 & 28.6 \\
    }\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            bar width=.5cm,
            width=\textwidth,
            height=.5\textwidth,
            legend style={at={(0.5,1)},
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={0--2,2--5,5--10,10--20,20--50,50+},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            ymin=0,ymax=35,
            ylabel={\%},
        ]
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=carR]{\mydata};
        \legend{Trips, Distance, Energy}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I literally just copied this code and nothing else. The pdf did not compile and the errors shown were:

```
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/fpu', to which you passed 'true', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Missing \begin{document}. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit near '28.45274'.. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The providesign increasing positions. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unitnear '56.9055'.. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The providesign increasing positions. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unitnear '56.9055'.. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Missing number, treated as zero. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Missing number, treated as zero. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit near '85.35826'.. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The providen increasing positions. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit near '85.35826'.. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Missing number, treated as zero. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Missing number, treated as zero. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Missing number, treated as zero. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit '0.0'.. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Missing number, treated as zero. ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
Undefined control sequence. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/fpu', to which you passed 'true', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `Y' or `Y0' (in '0Y0.0e0]'). ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Undefined control sequence. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Missing \begin{document}. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `Y' or `Y2' (in '1Y2.845274e1]'). ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Undefined control sequence. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Undefined control sequence. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit0'.. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The providePlease assign increasing positions. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Undefined control sequence. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Undefined control sequence. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Undefined control sequence. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Undefined control sequence. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit0'.. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Missing number, treated as zero. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Undefined control sequence. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit '0.0'.. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Missing number, treated as zero. ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...edcolormap}{color=(black) color=(black)}
Undefined control sequence. }
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/fpu', to which you passed 'true', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. }
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `Y' or `Y0' (in '0Y0.0e0]'). }
Undefined control sequence. }
Missing \begin{document}. }
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `Y' or `Y2' (in '1Y2.845274e1]'). }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit0'.. }
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The provide (color no 1) . Please assign increasing positions. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit0'.. }
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The provide. Please assign increasing positions. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit0'.. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The provide . Please assign increasing positions. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The provide. Please assign increasing positions. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The provide . Please assign increasing positions. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The provide . Please assign increasing positions. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The provide. Please assign increasing positions. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The provide. Please assign increasing positions. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Package pgfplots Error: Colormaps must have increasing positions. The provide . Please assign increasing positions. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit.. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Missing number, treated as zero. }
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }
Undefined control sequence. }
Undefined control sequence. }
Overfull \hbox (63.89009pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (98.61243pt too wide) in paragraph
```

I don't understand any of this (I use Texstudio) and I don't have the slightest idea what to do. If a solution to this problem already exists, please share the link. I am sorry if my English was not completely clear. Many thanks to whoever will help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Using recent `pgfpolts` package (version 1.16) I can't reproduce any error. Try to update your LaTeX installation or at least your `pgfplots` package

Comment: I updated both but nothing changes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't know if only the first few lines would be useful. This is the log of the first error:
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplots@createcolormap ...pgflibraryfpuifactive 
                             {\def \pgfplots@createcolo...
l.2482 ...; color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: Just to be sure: you literally try to compile the above, and do not use the plot in another document in which you, say, also load the babel package?

Comment: yes, litterally just the code above and nothing else. Doesn't work

Comment: Done: uninstalled the package and then redownloaded it. Thank you all

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the problem appears to have been caused by a faulty package, and reinstalling said package fixed it.

Comment: (If I misunderstood your latest comment, just ping me and I'll retract the close vote.)